# Unit test for helpers Ember-cli

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-testing

When I create a new helper on Ember CLI, a test is created inside `tests/unit/helpers`. I would like to know how to test this helpers using the unit test?. I tried to find a documentation, but nothing helps. I need to test the function `createArray` in order to pass the test coverage to a 100%.

Now, this is my helper:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function createArray(array) {
    return array;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(createArray);
```

This is my unit test: `tests/unit/helpers/create-array-test.js`

```
module('Unit | Helper | create array');

// Replace this with your real tests.
test('it works', function(assert) {
  let result = createArray([42]);
  assert.ok(result);
});
```

Hope someone can guide me.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Ember CLI are you using? The blueprint should generate a test file with an `import` of the named export so you can use it directly.

What `export function createArray` does is create a [named export](http://jsmodules.io/) named `createArray`. This means you can import the function directly and use it like you a normal function:

```
import { createArray } from 'app-name/helpers/create-array'

createArray(arrayOfArguments);
```

I modified [@ykaragol's Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/dbbf36c9f6835329026fd5cde219b4be?fileTreeShown=false&numColumns=2&openFiles=tests.unit.helper.my-helper-test.js%2Chelpers.my-helper.js) to demonstrate how to do this in a test:

```
import { createArray } from 'app-name/helpers/create-array';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

module('Unit | Helper | create array');

test('it works', function(assert) {
  let result = createArray([42]);
  assert.ok(result);
});
```

Replace `app-name` with the name of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted on twiddle helped me understand how to solve the helpers unit test. This is how I tested it, and it works like a charm.

```
test('Return the argument is passed', function(assert) {
  assert.ok(createArray([8,4,5,6]));
  assert.ok(createArray(['test1','test2','test3']));
});
```